# Vue/Nuxt: How can I access Nuxt instance in vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I would like to write a getter to return `this.$nuxt.$loading` from a vuex store file.
(https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/)

This question is linked to my other question: [Nuxt/Vue: How to position custom loading component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279498/nuxt-vue-how-to-position-custom-loading-component)

And now I thought of listening to this loading property to display my Loading component within the page.

The Loading property looks like this:

[image]

So I would like to return `this.$nuxt.$loading.data.$route.show` from the vuex store. If it is true, I want to show my custom loader and if its false not – of course.

To do that I would like to access `this.$nuxt` but this is undefined in my vuex store. It is only present in my components...
I tried `$nuxt` – same result.

I don't know if this is right or at least one way to achieve what I want, and I am definitely open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can use window.$nuxt for this.

Comment: I get `ERROR  window is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned this doesn't work when using SSR.

Answer (score 0):

I used `this._vm`.

You can see it in there if you do `console.log(this)` in Vuex.